# @remoteAction living with @invocablemethod

Tags: remote-action, invocable-method

I have built a class that calls a system external to Salesforce for checking customer's data. The service is an electronic VAT check provided by the state in the form of a very simple API.

I want to be able to call that class both via Javascript remoting (using @remoteAction annotation), from a Lightning Component (using @auraneabled annotation) and from a Flow (using @invocableMethod annotation).

The use cases are: call the eVAT service both from the client side (when the customer first inputs its data on registration), and from the back-end side (when a financial manager wants to check that VAT data is correct for existing customers)

Am I forced to design a class with two almost identical methods (one with @remote and one with @invocable) or are there better strategies / workarounds?

Thanks in advance for the answer coming from your hive brain, fellow SF folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't stack `@InvocableMethod` annotations.

> Other annotations can’t be used with the InvocableMethod annotation.

Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm)

However, what I'd normally do is make these methods wrappers, so you'd have one method like this:

```
@InvocableAction
public static List<String> getAccountNameList(List<ID> ids) {
  return getAccountNamesInternal(ids);
}

@AuraEnabled
@RemoteAction
public static List<String> getAccountNames(List<ID> ids) {
  return getAccountNamesInternal(ids);
}

private static List<String> getAccountNamesInternal(List<ID> ids) {
  //do common stuff here
}
```

This will at least keep these extra methods very small and easily maintainable.
Notice you CAN stack the other annotations, saving you an extra method.

Comment: Thanks Caspar, that's the design I'll go for then :)